# tableau color code one measure ruins subtotal on the crosstab

Tags: tableau-api, desktop

my crosstab has multiple dimensions and 3 measures. I have to color code one measure based on a condition and able to do it using the condition and measure names on the color mark. But this changes my subtotals, instead of sum it shows all values .

Subtotal to show the correct total